# How to add image border-radius in github pages

Tags: html, css

I am using github pages to create a portfolio blog with Jekyll theme and i want to set image border-radius to circle and i can't figure out to do that.This is what i have tried and nothing is happening to image. here is my code

```
  <a href="url"><img src="https://desmond75.github.io/img/IMG_20171214_095012.jpg" height="auto" width="200" style="border-radius:50%"></a>
```

i don't know if there is a way of doing this, i need help thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

This works

```
  <a href="url"><img src="https://desmond75.github.io/img/IMG_20171214_095012.jpg" height="auto" width="200" style="border-radius:50%"></a>
```

Comment: They are the same picture

Comment: https://github.community/t/github-flavored-markdown-doesnt-render-css-styles-inside-a-html-block/126258/2

Comment: Doesn't work for me..